# Is it possible to plot a list of identical points on a matplotlib hexbin plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this very simple code that is plotting a list of 100 points (10,10) that are all identical. Unfortunately, I am receiving a warning and a blank graph.

**My Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mylist = list()
for i in range(100):
    mylist.append(10)

def plot():

    plt.subplot(111)
    plt.hexbin(mylist,mylist,bins='log', cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r)
    plt.axis([0,50,0,50])

    plt.show()

plot()
```

**The Warning:**
[image]

1. Is it not possible to plot identical data on in a `hexbin`?
2. Am I doing something wrong?

**My specific situation:**

I understand this may be a strange question, but my program is plotting a large amount of points (x,y) (into the `hexbin` of course) and sometimes the points may all be identical.

If I slightly alter the code above and throw a different point (x,y) in at `list[i]` (i being any index) the code runs great and plots the data.

Comment: This is in fact a bug https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2863

Comment: I'm actually revisiting this issue now. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it? Maybe I will just have to throw an arbitrary data point outside of the scope of the graphs so that it always plots the data? @tcaswell

Comment: see edits to my answer.  Just make user you use the `extent` kwarg and you will avoid this bug entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it is trying to guess the limits of the grid by looking at the maximum and minimum `x` and `y` values and makes the step size `sx = (x_max - x_min) / num_x_bins` which is strictly zero in the case of this input.  The solution is to tell the code how big to make the array using the `extent` keyword.

```
mylist = list()
for i in range(100):
    mylist.append(10)

def plot():

    plt.subplot(111)
    plt.hexbin(mylist,mylist,bins='log', cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r, extent=[0, 50, 0, 50])
    plt.axis([0,50,0,50])

    plt.show()

plot()
```

There is a PR to fix this (that should be in 1.4 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3038)

In the meantime I would use something like (not tested, there may be some trivial bugs in here):

```
import matplotlib.transfroms as mtrans
def safe_hexbin(ax, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
      if 'extent' not in kwargs:
          xmin = np.amin(x)
          xmax = np.amax(x)
          ymin = np.amin(y)
          ymax = np.amax(y)
          # to avoid issues with singular data, expand the min/max pairs
          xmin, xmax = mtrans.nonsingular(xmin, xmax, expander=0.1)
          ymin, ymax = mtrans.nonsingular(ymin, ymax, expander=0.1)
          kwargs['extent'] = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
      return ax.hexbin(x, y, *args, **kwargs)


safe_hexbin(plt.gca(), x, y, ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple of problems with what you're doing:

1. using zeros with log values
2. your `myList` values are all 10
3. possibly not providing `hexbins` with all the input necessary for your use case

So I get output with this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.logspace(-1, 2)
y = np.logspace(-1, 2)
x = np.hstack([x, x])  # duplicate all points
y = np.hstack([y, y])  # duplicate all points
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
C = xx**2 + 10./yy**2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hexbin(x, y, C, bins='log', cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In reference to your second point - that is intentional. The points that I am plotting may very well be all "(10,10)".